# JavaScript: How to get all object values of an object without iterator

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I convert multidimensional array to object and when I try to return the converted object, I get only the first row values.

Here is my code.

```
const price = [
    [
      [1642636800000, 6.479682086929113],
      [1642723200000, 6.34357451008912],
      [1642809600000, 5.121543485810777],
      [1642896000000, 3.9740756848518095],
      [1642982400000, 4.3575187509716],
      [1643068800000, 3.9012325159931027],
      [1643155200000, 3.4317289914580345],
      [1643241600000, 3.2757454409610474],
      [1643328000000, 2.638504600238906],
      [1643414400000, 2.7780564535948247],
      [1643500800000, 2.6434238272520734],
      [1643587200000, 2.4336766397631195],
      [1643673600000, 2.3564650737278945],
      [1643760000000, 2.0999935033955395],
      [1643846400000, 2.030984947088804],
      [1643932800000, 1.9601855774194021],
      [1644019200000, 1.939260102893443],
      [1644105600000, 1.9099357711674574],
      [1644192000000, 1.756137354391081],
      [1644278400000, 1.5997203967365643],
      [1644364800000, 1.5123161188548575],
      [1644451200000, 1.519374648506311],
      [1644537600000, 1.537046985055748],
      [1644624000000, 1.508372954955599],
      [1644710400000, 1.55420714318404],
      [1644796800000, 1.5875532111414001],
      [1644883200000, 1.6653755421073082],
      [1644969600000, 1.6647861014789664],
      [1645056000000, 1.7214785428910968],
      [1645142400000, 1.7801924052482303],
      [1645177320000, 1.7624504335296196],
    ],
  ];
```

code to convert `price` array to JSON object

```
 const prices = price.map(function (value, key) {
    return {
      first: value[0][1],
      second: value[0][1],
    };
  });


console.log(prices); //prints only the first rows
```

How can I get all rows of the object?

Thanks

Comment: You have an array in array, so `price[0].map(function (value, key) { return { first: value[0], second: value[1], }; });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem here is that you have three dimensional array so when you map over it, it will only map over the elements inside first array to do what you want you can try this

```
    price.map(function (item) {
    return item.map(function (item) {
      return { first: item[0], second: item[1] };
    });
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

:)

```js
const prices = price[0].map(function(value, key) {
  return {
    first: value[0],
    second: value[1],
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const pricesArr = [
    [
      [1642636800000, 6.479682086929113],
      [1642723200000, 6.34357451008912],
      [1642809600000, 5.121543485810777],
      [1642896000000, 3.9740756848518095],
      [1642982400000, 4.3575187509716],
      [1643068800000, 3.9012325159931027],
      [1643155200000, 3.4317289914580345],
      [1643241600000, 3.2757454409610474],
      [1643328000000, 2.638504600238906],
      [1643414400000, 2.7780564535948247],
      [1643500800000, 2.6434238272520734],
      [1643587200000, 2.4336766397631195],
      [1643673600000, 2.3564650737278945],
      [1643760000000, 2.0999935033955395],
      [1643846400000, 2.030984947088804],
      [1643932800000, 1.9601855774194021],
      [1644019200000, 1.939260102893443],
      [1644105600000, 1.9099357711674574],
      [1644192000000, 1.756137354391081],
      [1644278400000, 1.5997203967365643],
      [1644364800000, 1.5123161188548575],
      [1644451200000, 1.519374648506311],
      [1644537600000, 1.537046985055748],
      [1644624000000, 1.508372954955599],
      [1644710400000, 1.55420714318404],
      [1644796800000, 1.5875532111414001],
      [1644883200000, 1.6653755421073082],
      [1644969600000, 1.6647861014789664],
      [1645056000000, 1.7214785428910968],
      [1645142400000, 1.7801924052482303],
      [1645177320000, 1.7624504335296196],
    ],
  ];
  
   const prices = pricesArr.flat(1).map(price => ({
      first: price[0],
      second: price[1]
      }));

console.log(prices);
```

You have a nested array, you can flatten it first and then, iterate to create an array of object.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array inside an array. So you could make it simpler, like so:

```js
const price = [
    [
      [1642636800000, 6.479682086929113],
      [1642723200000, 6.34357451008912],
      [1642809600000, 5.121543485810777],
      [1642896000000, 3.9740756848518095],
      [1642982400000, 4.3575187509716],
      [1643068800000, 3.9012325159931027],
      [1643155200000, 3.4317289914580345],
      [1643241600000, 3.2757454409610474],
      [1643328000000, 2.638504600238906],
      [1643414400000, 2.7780564535948247],
      [1643500800000, 2.6434238272520734],
      [1643587200000, 2.4336766397631195],
      [1643673600000, 2.3564650737278945],
      [1643760000000, 2.0999935033955395],
      [1643846400000, 2.030984947088804],
      [1643932800000, 1.9601855774194021],
      [1644019200000, 1.939260102893443],
      [1644105600000, 1.9099357711674574],
      [1644192000000, 1.756137354391081],
      [1644278400000, 1.5997203967365643],
      [1644364800000, 1.5123161188548575],
      [1644451200000, 1.519374648506311],
      [1644537600000, 1.537046985055748],
      [1644624000000, 1.508372954955599],
      [1644710400000, 1.55420714318404],
      [1644796800000, 1.5875532111414001],
      [1644883200000, 1.6653755421073082],
      [1644969600000, 1.6647861014789664],
      [1645056000000, 1.7214785428910968],
      [1645142400000, 1.7801924052482303],
      [1645177320000, 1.7624504335296196],
    ],
  ];

const prices = price[0].map(value =>({first: value[0],second: value[1]}));
console.log(prices);
```